# Convex set definition

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Munkres defines thus: Given an ordered set $X$ a subset $Y$ of $X$ is convex in $X$ if for each pair of points $a<b$ of $Y$ the entire interval $(a,b)$ of points of $X$ lies in $Y$. But again in Connected subspaces of real line section he recalls the definition of convex but now using a closed interval $[a,b]$. Is it $(a,b)$ in the definition or $[a,b]$?

Comment: You already know that $a,b \in Y$ so $[a,b] \subseteq Y$ is equivalent to $(a,b) \subseteq Y$

Comment: Formallly: $\forall a,b \in Y: (\forall x \in X: ((a < x) \land (x < b)) \to x \in Y)$.